# Modifying handleChange function for a drop down selector React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I am new to react and I want to design a drop-down selector that has a handleChange function for later use.

```
const Countries = [
  { label: "Albania", value: 355 },
  { label: "Argentina", value: 54 },
  { label: "Austria", value: 43 },
  { label: "Cocos Islands", value: 61 },
  { label: "Kuwait", value: 965 },
  { label: "Sweden", value: 46 },
  { label: "Venezuela", value: 58 }
];

handleChange = input => e => {
  this.setState({ [input]: e.target.value }); 
}

<Select placeholder='Select Location'onChange={handleChange('Location')} defaultValue={values.Location} required options={Countries} />
```

this handleChange function works for textfields and inputs, but it doesnt match this drop down version. how should I implement a version that matches with this drop down?

Comment: IS Select from 'react-select'

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri yes

Comment: Take a look at `onChange` in the [props doc](https://react-select.com/props#select-props). It doesn't pass the event but the selected option.

Comment: Not my job to troubleshoot other people's bad answers, sorry :) Did you fully read the docs yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select gives you the selected value directly and not an event so that you can use it as it is. Also a default value can be set as `Countries[0]`

```
const Countries = [
  { label: "Albania", value: 355 },
  { label: "Argentina", value: 54 },
  { label: "Austria", value: 43 },
  { label: "Cocos Islands", value: 61 },
  { label: "Kuwait", value: 965 },
  { label: "Sweden", value: 46 },
  { label: "Venezuela", value: 58 }
];

handleChange = input => value => {
  this.setState({ [input]: value }); 
}

<Select placeholder='Select Location'onChange={handleChange('Location')} defaultValue={values.Location} required options={Countries} />
```

Comment: now I receive this Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {label, value}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: in the next page I want to show {Location} which is a props but I receive that error in the console

Comment: Whereever you are using Location to render, you need to use Location.label

Answer (score 0):

```
<Select placeholder='Select Location' onChange={(data) => handleChange(data)} defaultValue={values.Location} required options={Countries} />
```

you need to pass a function like `onChange={(data) => handleChange(data)}` so that can actually executes on onChange.

and inside that function

```
handleChange = input => {
 this.setState({ selectedValue: e.target.value }); 
}
```

it will set the whole object, while using you can take out `selectedValue.value`.